# Creating two Button Tables in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

What i would like is to create two arrays of Buttons like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLDT9.png).

What i have done so far :

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
           GridPane grid = new GridPane();
           Scene scene = new Scene(grid2, 1000, 1000);
           grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
           for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
               for(int j=0;j<9;j++) {
                        grid.add(new Button(), i,j);
                           }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

This creates the first desired array starting from the top left corner.However i can't seem to be able to  place the second one.Adding a button in a location like (40,40) puts it in a different place.How could this be done?

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is `grid2`? Create a method with the `GridPane` code that returns the `GridPane`. Call the method twice. Add it to a `VBox`.